# Which stotra are these verses from?

Tags: shloka, stotra, reference-request

In [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dNVBb6hucv8) video, Dr. Chidabaram Sastry gives two slokas for getting the Grace of Devi for Poetry prowess.

But it's hard for me to learn without knowing the lyrics.
The slokas are in the video at 0:22 and at 1:09. But from which stotra are them taken?

Comment: The slokas you are referring to start at exactly what time?

Comment: Sorry . It starts at 0:22 and at 1:09 sloka 2. Thanks

Comment: Okay so one that starts with Hroom hroom hroom ..

Comment: Yes and other starts with "sthvameetham " .

Comment: Okay so you can comment under the video too?

Comment: Yes but it's no use their . As channel never replies back as i did on other videos.

Comment: Oh okay .........

Comment: Edit your q and your title according to the rules.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a forum for 'authenticating' youtube videos. your question is best directed to the author of the youtube video

Comment: OP is just asking which stotras contain the slokas that are being chanted in the given video. There is nothing wrong with the question. @SwamiVishwananda

Comment: @Swamivishwananda You should teach us new meaning of words that are being chosen to close by you. Because author asks for where is source of sloka from scriptures contained in the video.  Nowhere author asks for verification of YouTube chant. Only when author asks what is authenticity of the youtube video your point is valid. Please stop this rude behaviour of closing questions wrongly. This isnt quality of a sadhaka.

Comment: @swami Vishwananda .I'm sorry if i offended anyone . But as Rickross and  Parabrahman Jyoti stated . I didn't asked for verification or authenticity of video. I just wanted to know the lyrics so that i can learn it as i find it's hard to learn without lyrics. So i asked for help not authentication.

Comment: @trilokreddy do not worry. Whatever questions he has voted to close so far none has been closed in history of this stack exchange. Wait for answer from one of members.

Comment: Thanks For having my Back. @Parabrahman Jyoti ,@Rickross